# Parse server dashboard login

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk, parse-dashboard

So, I am new to Android Studio. I'm following an online course step by step.
I'm using ParseServer on AWS. I've managed to get my appId, etc. and can connect with a Java SSH Client directly from my browser. My app can successfully store information in the ParseServer, but I can't access the parse dashboard. When I try to it asks me to enter my username and password -- which I don't have.

I've found a file (in bitnami terminal) and I think that I should maybe make myself an account in here?

```
# /home/bitnami/apps/parse/.forever/config.json


{
  "root": "/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/.forever",
  "pidPath": "/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/.forever/pids",
  "sockPath": "/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/.forever/sock",
  "loglength": 100,
  "logstream": false,
  "columns": [
    "uid",
    "command",
    "script",
    "forever",
    "pid",
    "id",
    "logfile",
    "uptime"
  ]
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see how the dashboard was configured.  Take a look at the readme for the dashboard: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard.  If you search for "password" on that page, you'll see the various ways that the dashboard can be configured (either env vars or a json file.)   Which one matches how you are setup?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've just edited.

Comment: @DDeex, that bitnami `.forever` directory is for a [process manager](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) not the parse-dashboard. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue lays with wherever you're instantiating the dashboard. For me, this is inside `index.js`.
`var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": process.env.SERVER_URL,
      "appId": process.env.APP_ID,
      "masterKey": process.env.MASTER_KEY,
      "appName": process.env.APP_NAME,
      "javascriptKey": process.env.JS_KEY,
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
        "user":<username>,
        "pass":<password>
    }
  ],
  "useEncryptedPasswords": true, //Requires Bcrypt encrypted passwords. Set to false if you want the explicit <password> plain text string to be your password)
  "trustProxy": 1
});`

Comment: Thank you, i did that and rebooted my instance (on aws) of the server and now it works. :)

Comment: Happy to help! There's quite the learning curve to this stuff, was hard enough when it was all hosted by Parse.

Comment: index.js is part of the parse-server-example. If you didn't start from there, you would have needed to create your own kind of file, or it's whatever you pass into `node run`. index.js is just the standard / default.

Comment: Also, every node module pretty much has an index.js, which means if you do a project search for it you'll find tons. You need the highest level index.js, like there should be on in top level folder, next to the node_modules directory.

Answer (score 4):

Thansk for answering my question!

The right answer is to find here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#how-to-find-application-credentials:

Username: user

Password: -> On EC2 / Amazon you must go this way: Instance Settings -> Get System Log -> Look for your password, which was given from system by setup

That's all!

Comment: Very Helpful! Wow this solved everything. Thank you!