# Login into Parse Dashboard on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, authentication, dashboard, parse-server

How can I login into my Parse Dashboard on Amazon EC2? When I take the offered Link ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-X.compute.amazonaws.com, he wants to have an username and a password. Which combination should I take?

Last week I only need to follow the link above und there I was ...

Best regards

UPDATE: Problem solved - in EC2 Logs you can see your password. It's automatically given to you by the system and can be viewed here again and again ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse server dashboard login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43296231/parse-server-dashboard-login)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you didnt view the link provided by the previous answer, i have edited it into a clearer view for you below.

```
var allowInsecureHTTP = true;
var parseDashboardSettings = {
  "apps": [{
    "serverURL": process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',
    "appId": process.env.APP_ID || '***',
    //"restAPIKey": process.env.RESTAPI_KEY || "***",
    "masterKey": process.env.MASTER_KEY || '***',
    "appName": process.env.APP_NAME || "***"
  }],
  "users": [{
    "user": "administrator", //REPLACE WITH YOURS
    "pass": "password", //REPLACE WITH YOURS
    "masterKey": process.env.MASTER_KEY || '***',
    "apps": [{
      "appId": process.env.APP_ID || '***'
    }]
  }]
}
var dashboard = new ParseDashboard(parseDashboardSettings, allowInsecureHTTP);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
```